# Show images in table from database in Asp.net-mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image

I have a table containing user information with image field and storing image in binary data.

I want to show this images on my view page in a table with user information.

my code is..
Controller

```
public ActionResult About()
        {
var data = db.dbtable.ToList();
return View(data);
}
```

Get Image method // reg is object of dbtable

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(int id)
        {            
            reg = db.dbtable.FirstOrDefault(i => i.RegNo == id);            
            if (reg != null)
            {
                return File(reg.Photo, "image/jpeg");
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

on view page..

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMySchool.dbtable>

<table width="50">
    <tr>
        <th> 
            Registration No.
        </th>
        <th>
            First Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Last Name
        </th>
        <th>
            City
        </th>
        <th>
            Photo
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RegNo)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
            </td>
            <td>
            @*HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<img width="75" height="75" src=@(Url.Action("GetImage", "Home", new { id = item.RegNo })) />")*@
                <img width="75" height="75" src=@(Url.Action("GetImage", "Home", new { id = item.RegNo })) />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

It only shows the image in the first row and nothing after that.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

May make more sense just to keep the path the image.

If you filesteam,

```
public FileStreamResult GetImage(int id)
{

reg = db.dbtable.FirstOrDefault(i => i.RegNo == id);            
            if (reg != null)
            {

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(reg.Photo);
    return File(ms, "image/png");

            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
}
```

more logical way to keep, ony way

```
public FileResult GetImage(int id)
{
reg = db.dbtable.FirstOrDefault(i => i.RegNo == id);            
                if (reg != null)
                {
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(reg.Photo));
    return File(fi.OpenRead, "image/png");
                }
}
```

for both

```
<tr>
    <td>
       <img src="/Home/GetImage/@item.RegNo" alt="" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: thanks for reply i first logic it show only one image on first row of table. i want all the images from the database and show each image in each table row..

Comment: Ok. 
`@foreach (var item in Model)
{<img src="/Home/GetImage/@item.RegNo" alt="" />}`

Comment: if you for path use `@foreach (var item in Model) {<img src="@item.PHOTO" alt="" />}` page in after render `<img src="/Content/Images/krish.png" alt="" />`

Comment: i m not having image in content folder in database image store in binary data (in byte)

Comment: Use first code sample **action** and use view **`<img src="/Home/GetImage/@item.RegNo" alt="" />`** for see image, browser url http://localhost/Home/GetImage/5

Comment: when i directly run url in explorer localhost/Home/GetImage/1 it show image but after id 1 (localhost/Home/GetImage/2, localhost/Home/GetImage/3 count.) it show error - The image "localhost/Home/GetImage/5" cannot be displayed because it contains error

Comment: For the records cannot be found, not `return null;` use return not found image path.